# cts:value-tuples with elements inside both document and properties fragment not working

Tags: marklogic

I have a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <a>2015-08-12T09:51:16-05:00</a>
```

In the same URI I have a property like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <prop:properties xmlns:prop="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property">
    <prop:b>2015-08-12T09:51:16-05:00</prop:b>
    </prop:properties>
```

I have range indexes of type `dateTime` on the elements `a` and `prop:b`. If I run a cts:values on `a` or `prop:b` I get the respective values from the lexicon , but when I run the following I get an empty sequence:

```
cts:value-tuples((cts:element-reference(xs:QName("prop:b")),
   cts:element-reference(xs:QName("a"))),("any"))
```

Please help me in figuring out what I am missing.

Version : 7.0.5

Comment: The docs talk about co-occurrences in the same fragments, and doc and property fragment are separate. But this does make sense, let me ask around internally..

Comment: I found the following options in the docs:   "any"
Co-occurrences from any fragment should be included.
"document"
Co-occurrences from document fragments should be included.
"properties"
Co-occurrences from properties fragments should be included.  I thought 'any'  would work. But it does not.

Comment: It means it includes co-occurrences from any fragment (doc and prop), but each co-occurrence should still occur within one fragment (doc or prop, not across both)..

Comment: Translated above comments to an answer..

Answer (score 1):

The `any` option means:

> Co-occurrences from any fragment should be included.

where any fragments includes `document`, `properties` and `lock` fragments.

The issue is though, that each co-occurrence still needs to occur ***within*** one and the same fragment, regardless which one. So `a` in the document fragment, and `prop:b` in the properties fragment are never going to be returned as co-occurrence. The only way to make this work is by putting `a` and `prop:b` in the same fragment.

One recommended way is by wrapping your document in an extra root element to allow for sibling elements. This is a very common pattern in MarkLogic, called the Envelope Pattern. The extra room is often used for things like provenance, additional metadata, embedded triples, normalized values, etc. In your case it could look as simple as:

```
<envelope>
  <header>
    <prop:b>2015-08-12T09:51:16-05:00</prop:b>
  </header>
  <content>
    <a>2015-08-12T09:51:16-05:00</a>
  </content>
</envelope>
```

The names of the wrapper elements don't really matter, but element names like `envelope`, `header`, and `content` are fairly common. It can be useful to put those wrapper elements in a separate namespace, to make it easier to distinguish them.

HTH!